# complexity of Tinder's swipe matching process patent

Tags: patent-applications, software, utility, utility-patent, software-as-a-service

https://patents.google.com/patent/US11513666B2/en

The above patent is for a feature in a dating app that protects Tinder's swipe matching process.

Most law firms assess application complexity and therefore cost by 3 tiers:

```
a. simple
b. moderate
c. complex
```

1. Based upon complexity assessed against all utility patent types, what tier of complexity is Tinder's patent?
2. Based upon complexity assessed against only software patents, what tier of complexity is Tinder's patent?

Comment: I imagine different law firms have different rubrics for fitting potential applications to complexity (i.e., pricing) tiers. The only good answer is to simply get multiple quotes and see where you feel you are getting the best value (which may not necessarily be the cheapest option, since the quality of the resulting application matters too).

Comment: @bhuff36 That could be posted as a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer. I do have a number of patents. I'd guess that the cited patent is considered complex to prosecute. I say that with only a casual skim of the patent. For one, the independent claims are among the longest I've ever seen. However that isn't why I think it is complex. The most important issue with complexity is how many other patents and sources of prior art exist and are relevant. I imagine there are a lot in this field so the patent attorneys need to review and assess a lot of art. With lawyers, time is money.